# Magento 2 Import CSV File upload option dissapearing

Tags: magento2, javascript, php-7

Magento 2.2.2

I am trying to upload a csv file for an import.

However when I select Entity Product

the option for uploading the csv in admin dissapears.

I have tried resetting permission for directories but problem is still there.

Please can anyone provide suggestion as to why this could be happening.

Comment: please let me know is this issue happening on server (or) local instance? have you verified logs exception (or) debug (or) system logs? if not please verify logs using tail -f var/log/exception.log from M2 root. Try to identify issue on local first able to reproduce or not..

Comment: thanks - site is on live dedicated server, there is nothing in the magento or server logs.